# Difference between using hardwareserial.h and serial2 with ESP32 in arduino IDE

Tags: arduino, esp32, arduino-esp32

I am using ESP32(esp32-wroom-32) and GPS neo-6m.

- GPS serial ports are connected to Rx2 and Tx2 of esp32
- GPS vcc and gnd connected to vcc and gnd of ESP32

I am using arduino IDE for development.

we can read data from UART2 using below methods

First

```
void setup()  
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  Serial2.begin(115200); 
 
} 
void loop()  
{ 
  Serial.print(Serial2.read());

  
}
```

Second

```
#include <HardwareSerial.h>

HardwareSerial SerialPort(2); // use UART2
void setup()  
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  SerialPort.begin(115200, SERIAL_8N1, 16, 17); 
 
} 
void loop()  
{ 
  Serial.print(SerialPort.read());

  
}
```

What is the difference in above methods and scenarios based on which we select one of the above methods ?

P.S I am new to Arduino IDE and micro controller programming.

Comment: core has `HardwareSerial Serial2(2);`. and begin is `void begin(unsigned long baud, uint32_t config=SERIAL_8N1, int8_t rxPin=-1, int8_t txPin=-1, ...`.  and `if (rxPin < 0 && txPin < 0) {rxPin = RX2;  txPin = TX2;}` and RX2 and TX2 depends on selected board

Comment: Is this a typo? `Serial2.begin(15200);`

Comment: wrong baud rate ?

Answer (score 0):

because some boards already come with a second set of serial ports and some boards don't. If the board already has designated second set, you don't need the HardwareSerial library.

Answer (score 0):

Both sections of code perform same function.
The difference is
FirstCase-> uses Serial2 object defined in hardwareserial.cpp library file
SecondCase-> Port object is declared in the same file.

They both function same with no performance difference, it's individual preference.
I would go with secondcase, because the definition is inside same code file.